# Why Ubuntu does not see npm? sudo: npm: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, npm

I run

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

got

```
sudo: npm: command not found
```

Let's check

```
nvm install v20.0.0
v20.0.0 is already installed.
Now using node v20.0.0 (npm v9.6.4)
```

and

```
which npm
/home/miki/.nvm/versions/node/v20.0.0/bin/npm
```

why it seems that npm is not installed? I am on Ubunutu 22.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suite appears to be installed in your home directory, so you shouldn't need any special permissions to install further packages. I expect, therefore, that your own `$PATH` has been updated but the system one has not. (If it had been installed for the system you would need system privileges.)

Try this, i.e. without `sudo`:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```